# UWP - ListBoxItem - Click Trigger.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, listbox, uwp

I´ve an UWP application with a ListBox. 
When I click on a related listboxitem I change a frame content. ( I am using the SelectionChanged event for this. ) 
Inside this Frame I can go and do multiple operations such as move into another Page Frame. (And keep the sme listboxItem selected. )

So I have -> MainPage -> ContactsPage -> ContactsDetailPage. (On the listBox I have the "Contacts" item selected). 
But, if on "ContactsDetailsPage" I click on "Contacts" ListBoxItem the SelectionChanged doesnt trigger ( Because it is selected). So, I cannot navigate to "Contact" Page.

There is another event I can use to navigate when I click on ListBoxItem ? Or do you can suggest another options ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You may always set index to -1 after your logic and ignore it when it's fired:

```
    private void ListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
        //your logic
        ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: I had tried something similar.. But when I set the SelectedIndex to -1 , it removes the Active colors for the selected ListBoxItem. There is another way to set the selected item color ?

Comment: Yap, you can do something like " Contacts.Background =  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);" and set the color programatly. It is not the perfect solution But it works