# List View Double Tapped Item

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am currently making an application with multiple ListViewItems in a ListView that react to a double click event. However, I need to know what item was double clicked when a double click fires on the ListView.

When a List View in UWP is double tapped, it doesn't select the item before firing the double click event. As a result, I cannot get the item through myListView.SelectedItem. UWP doesn't seem to have supports for hit tests either unless I am missing something.

Thoughts?

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812310/uwp-listboxitem-click-trigger/45814015#45814015 you may also create a field to save the previous selected index to compare for double-click

Comment: The selection changed never fires when an item is double tapped. That is the root of my issue.

Comment: Try to register the DoubleTapped event on the DataTemplate of ListViewItem, instead of the ListView.

Comment: @kennyzx I originally tried to register the double tapped event of the listviewitem when I created it and added it to the listview. However, I needed to receive a reference to the listviewitem that was clicked and since my item contains a textbox, it would occasionally return the textbox if that item was clicked. Is there a way to use the event args to get the listviewitem or (in the case the item is a textbox) the items parent?

Comment: Fixed my own issue! I will post my solution this afternoon. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue by doing the following:

1. I set the IsHitTestVisible property on the grid inside in the Listviewitem to be false (only applicable if you have controls inside of your list view).
2. I subscribed to the ListView's double tapped event
3. Upon the event firing, I used the DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs to grab the original source and casted that to Listviewitem (or in my case, my usercontrol).

Here's the code:

Custom Listviewitem:
XAML

```
<ListViewItem x:Name="ListBoxItemContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0,0">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <!-- Your controls here -->
    </Grid>
</ListViewItem>
```

List View Code:

```
private async void MainListView_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var test = (ListViewItem)MainListView.SelectedItem;
        // Test is your reference to the list view item that was clicked
    }
```

Note: Make sure you subscribe to your list view's double tapped event.

Comment: If the user double clicks on an area of the list view that does not have an item then using the SelectedItem is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListView.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

        _previousIndex = ListView.SelectedIndex;

        if (_previousIndex == ListView.SelectedIndex)
        {
            //double-click occured
            _previousIndex = -2;
        }

        ListView.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: As posted on your original comment, the onselectionchanged event never fires when an item is double clicked.

Comment: using it you do not need to subscribe to any double clicks